# How to post array to a php server in android?

Tags: java, php, android, json, post

I am using DataOutputStream class to send my data as post data to a php server

```
DataOutputStream dataOutputStreamRegister = new DataOutputStream(connectionToRegister.getOutputStream());
dataOutputStreamRegister.writeBytes("txtUserID="+userName+"&txtPassword="+userPassword+"&ddlCountry="+countryId
                    +"&ddlUniversity="+universityId+"&ddlCourseYear="+courseYearId+"&txtEmail="+userEmail+"&txtInitial="+userInitials
                    +"&txtFname="+userFirstName+"&txtLname="+userLastName+"&txtDob="+userBirthMonth+"/"+userBirthDay+"/"+userBirthYear
                    +"&ddlLevel="+levelId+"&txtSkills="+studentSkills+"&ddlGender="+genderId+"&ddlFraternity="+fraternityId+"&ddlSorority="
                    +sororityId+"&ddlClubs="+paramsText);
```

The last parameter "ddlClubs" i want to send should be like an array.The code in the php server is as follows

```
foreach($_POST["ddlClubs"] as $key=>$val){
 ....
}
```

How should i go about doing this as many techniques i saw included deprecated classes like "defaultHttpClient" and "NameValuePairs"

Thanks everyone for your time.

Comment: Search for `OkHTTP` library.

Comment: @PrerakSola Thanks for your reply.Can i not do this without using any library?

Comment: Just format your url accordingly: ``...&ddlClubs[0]=value0&ddlClubs[1]=value1`` and so on.

Comment: @f1sh ok trying your suggestion and letting you know.

Comment: @f1sh yes have worked.Please write this as an answer so that i may accept it and other users can check with this simple answer instead of the more complicated ones on stackoverflow

Comment: @Debojyoti done. Good luck with your further work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just format your url accordingly:

```
...&ddlClubs[0]=value0&ddlClubs[1]=value1
```

This also works with associative arrays, such as:

```
&ddlClubs[name0]=value0&ddlClubs[name1]=value1
```

Unfortunately this has its limits as [a url has a maximum length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers), meaning you cannot put a very huge array into the url.